# Why are moderator delete votes hyperlinks but community votes aren't?

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign, deleted-answers

As shown in this example, delete votes cast by moderators link to their profile but delete votes cast by 10k users do not.

[image: Screenshot of deleted post where moderator profiles are linked but not 10k users]

What is the rationale behind this?

I'm going to also tag this as a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) *until proved otherwise*, as the behaviour is different from that of close votes, which link to all the voters' (moderator or close vote privilege) profile pages.

Comment: Can you add the link to the exact post? On other sites I see regular users linked in the delete vote list (see e.g. http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/108953/whats-the-fastest-way-to-climb-craggy-rock-walls/121051#121051).

Comment: @MadScientist http://biology.stackexchange.com/a/7661/69

Comment: Working fine [here on Meta](http://i.stack.imgur.com/uvssX.png) and on the [main site](http://i.stack.imgur.com/jHBLz.png). Maybe only for beta sites?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Just checked this on Workplace (beta site) normal users are given a link still. So not because of that.

Comment: @Rory what about other deleted posts? Maybe it's specific to that answer?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Yeah I did wonder about that, however I'm really struggling to find another post that has been deleted by mods *and* normal users.  Can anyone think of a good way to find one?

Comment: @Rory as mod, just go over the flag history. Many times when 10K user flag as "not an answer" he also vote to delete, that's what I'm doing often.

Comment: @ShaWiz our community seem to like to keep their delete votes - went through every NAA in the flag history and didn't find a single one that hadn't just been mod-hammered into dust, then again we only really have 4 active users with the trusted user privilege so it's perhaps not surprising that they're few and far between.  I'll ask someone to cast a delete vote on a worthy answer assuming I can find one

Comment: @Rory cheers, keep us informed here on far away Meta! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are no longer linked if the user does not exist anymore - at that Id.  This can also include user merges where the master user Id is the *other* user, due to how that data is denormalized.